ERROR - Unable to retrieve variable from secrets backend (Airflow)
We are using Airflow 2.6.
We have a number of DAGs which traditionally have run without issue.
Of late however we are seeing a number of issues relating to this error below;
ERROR - Unable to retrieve variable from secrets backend (MetastoreBackend). Checking subsequent secrets backend.
Any tips greatly appreciated.
What we have done to mitigate this is include re-tries of the DAGs which has allowed us to not manually re-run DAGs as often.
We did enable PgBouncer on the Airflow server to see if this helped but to no avail.

What does your secrets config look like? -- this does not seem like a solution to fix using PgBouncer, you are very likely hitting the error based on config issues

It looks like it is not defined in the airflow.cfg file, should this be altered do you feel?

Yes, that is what the error states...but please post an example of your config if you keep having issues after adding the right variables

[secrets]
Full class name of secrets backend to enable (will precede env vars and metastore in search path)
Example: backend = airflow.providers.amazon.aws.secrets.systems_manager.SystemsManagerParameterStoreBackend
backend =
The backend_kwargs param is loaded into a dictionary and passed to init of secrets backend class.
See documentation for the secrets backend you are using. JSON is expected.
Example for AWS Systems Manager ParameterStore:
{"connections_prefix": "/airflow/connections", "profile_name": "default"}
backend_kwargs =

I have added the secrets info per above, we also get this accompanying error if that is of any use; ((psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "XXX.rds.amazonaws.com" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
